# Ajax submit Form sometimes works, sometimes redirects to the action-url directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I display a lot of courses with a foreach loop in a table!
Each course has its own form with the id, and a submit button!

```
<form id="kurs<?php echo $result["ID"]; ?>" name="kurs<?php echo $result["ID"]; ?>" action="test.php" method="POST">
...form-field..
<input type="submit" id="submitid" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Aktualisieren">
</form>
```

Below (inside the foreach) there is this script:

```
$("#submitid").click(function() {
  $("#kurs<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      url: formURL,
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#item-<?php echo $result["ID"]; ?>').addClass('bg-success border');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#item-<?php echo $result["ID"]; ?>').removeClass('bg-success border')
        }, 1500);
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
  });
});

$("#kurs<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").submit();
```

The Problem is that it just works 50%?

**Half of the time the form gets normally submitted and i land on the test.php page**, the other times, the data gets updatet and the row blinks green for a few seconds as it should be!

When it works it works, when not i can reload and maybe then it works!

Somebody has an idea?

**Edit:**
I found out that everything works fine if I start everything by clicking the FIRST  input.. if i start with another row it doesnt work!

Comment: Do u want AJAX or submit reload?

Comment: i think ajax? but sometimes it just submits the form normaly and brings me to test.php instead of staying on the same page and just add the classes to the row for a few seconds

Comment: Binding events inside of a click is a BAD BAD BAD idea.

Comment: yes and here its Click inside Click

Comment: why is this a bad bad idea? and how could i do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem is that it just works 50%? ... Half of the time the form gets normally submitted and i land on the test.php page, the other times, the data gets updatet and the row blinks green for a few seconds as it should be!

I don't understand why you have two identical `.submit()` handlers...

```
$("#submitid").click(function() {
      $("#kurs<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").submit(function(e) {
          .....
          // your ajax()
          .....
      });
});

$("#kurs<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").submit(); // <-- same as above
```

One is inside your `click` handler and contains `ajax()`, the other is outside the `click` handler and will just submit to the default form `action`.  So it's completely understandable that if your `ajax()` is not reached quickly enough, then the code execution will reach the second submit handler and just submit to the default `action`.  Whichever `.submit()` handler is reached first is the one that wins... in your case, truly a coin toss.

You already have a real submit button inside of your form so there is absolutely no reason for any `click` handler function and certainly no reason for two `submit` handlers.

Simply do this...

```
$("#kurs<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var postData = $(this).serialize();
      var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
      $.ajax({
           ....
      });
});
```

Comment: oh thank you very much I haven't seen this answer ^^ i hat two submit events because i found this script somewhere in the internet and dont know much about javascript.. but thank you, because of your answer i think i understand it a little bit more ;)

Answer (score 0):

on the first line of your js submit function put `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Sorry I missed the nested click functions.  That is why it doesn't work

Comment: do you mean that i first have 'click-function' and then 'submit-function'? i dont know how i should make it :(

Comment: I just typed a long response to you and the saw @Sparky's response.  That is exactly what you need to do

Comment: didnt saw it ;) now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got the problem!

Maybe its not the best way, that i have nested functions but i dont know how to do it in an other way so its okay for me ;)

I had to add also unique ID's to the submitbuttons..

```
<input type="submit" id="submitid<?php echo $result["ID"]; ?>" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Aktualisieren">
```

and

```
             $("#submitid<?php echo $result['ID']; ?>").click(function() {
```

Comment: We assumed you already knew that!  Any duplicate `id` is invalid HTML.    You're creating the `id` with PHP, for what good reason, if not to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Still no good reason for you to have a `click` handler when you have a real `submit` button.

Comment: ahhhh haha .. i dont really get it! can i delete the whole submitid.click(function) ? just with the submit(function) it doesnt seem to work

Comment: I showed you and explained it very simply in my answer.  **The click handler is NOT needed**.  Just put the `ajax()` inside of a ONE `submit()` handler.  If the form ID is correct, it works... that's how it's done.